# jQuery ui sortable inaccurate placeholder placement in nested sortables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've a sortable element inside another sortable element. Both are connected to each other. 
Following the the sample markup:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>1</div>
    <div class='child'>2</div>
    <div class='child'>3</div>
    <div class='child'>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>5</div>
    <div class='child'>6</div>
    <div class='child'>7</div>
    <div class='child'>8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is to drag multiple items between `.parent`'s and `#container`.

Following is the JS:

```
$("#container").on('click', '.child', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('.parent').sortable({
  appendTo: "#container",
  connectWith: '.parent, #container',
  revert: 0,
  helper: function (e, item) {
    if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
        item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
    var elements = $('#container').find('.selected').clone();
    $('#container').find('.selected').not(item).addClass('hidden');
    var helper = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'parent'
    });
    return helper.append(elements);
  },
  start: function (e, ui) {
    var len = ui.helper.children().length;
    var width = ui.item.width() + 2;
    ui.helper.width((len * width));
    ui.placeholder.width((len * width));
  },
  stop: function (e, ui) {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  }
});

$('#container').sortable({
  connectWith: '.parent',
  tolerance: "pointer"
});
```

The following

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/6opxyvkp/4/)

with the whole code (*I removed the code for appending items to minimize the code since that is not relevant to the placeholder position*) demonstrates the issue i'm facing:

I'm able to drag items from `.parent` to the  `#container` as follows:

- By dragging the items to the left of `#container` as shown below:
  [image]
- By dragging items above `#container` through the space between `.parents` (*This is a bit tricky but it works when the center is exactly hovered over the space*) as shown below:
  [image]

**But** Once i drag an item outside, the placeholder does not appear to the right side of `#container` even when i directly hover the item over it.

Expected output:

[image: desired outpuy]

Current result:

[image: current output]

As shown in the image, the placeholder is inside the `.parent` even though the item is away from it, inside `#container`.

From what i tried, the issue is with the following:

```
 $('#container').find('.selected').not(item).addClass('hidden');
```

Where i hide the selected items using `display:none`, Possibly causing miscalculations with jQuery UI.

So i tried [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) and [refreshPositions](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refreshPositions) in the [start](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start) event, as in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/6opxyvkp/1/), Which is produces the expected output, but it no longer properly displays the placeholder in `#container` in the other two scenario.

What i want to do is to be able to drag items from `.parent` to `#container` by

1. Dragging items to the left of `#container`
2. Dragging items above `#container` through the space between `.parents`
3. Dragging items to the right of `#container`

*Side note: Most of the [sortable options](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#options) are added while trying to fix the issue, and the css dimensions are for demo purpose only, these can be added or removed if necessary.*

**Update:** this seems like a bug, which i reported [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10578). The jQuery UI team replied that  they  are in the process of rewriting all interactions. So hopefully this will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: First you said `As shown in the image, the placeholder is inside the .parent even though the item is away from it, inside #container.` .. I just checked it and the placeholders are outside the parent, just a child of container, am I right? check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/4j2qpl

Comment: Well you probably took that screenshot from second fiddle, in which i'm unable to create the placeholder in container on the left side along with other issues as i mentioned in the question... Did you check whether you can perform all the three actions in same fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

In my code, it has almost become a convention to just apply this poorly documented hack to Sortable’s `over` and `out` callback functions:

```
if($.ui.ddmanager.current)
    $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets($.ui.ddmanager.current, null);
```

This will make sure positions are refreshed, and in contrast to the built-in `refresh` and `refreshPositions` methods, it seems to work.

Could you try this approach, and see if it improves your Sortable’s behavior?

Comment: Dude, you made my day! As you said, unlike the documented refresh and refreshPositions methods, this ACTUALLY seems to work!

Comment: Are you sayign to add this to the user defined functions, or to the functions in the core Jquery UI codebase?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Never mind the third-party plugin, check this out let me know if this is what you were after: http://jsfiddle.net/6opxyvkp/7/ - **old**

http://jsfiddle.net/6opxyvkp/9/ - **new**

**HTML**

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='child'>1</div>
        <div class='child'>2</div>
        <div class='child'>3</div>
        <div class='child'>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='parent'>
        <div class='child'>5</div>
        <div class='child'>6</div>
        <div class='child'>7</div>
        <div class='child'>8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    height:60px;
    background:dodgerblue;
}
.parent {
    float:left;
    height:58px;
    margin:0 15px;
    border:0px solid red;
    background:silver;
}
.child {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:60px;
    text-align: left;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:0px;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    visibility: visible !important;
    border: none;
    padding:1px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
.selected {
    background:red;
}
.hidden {
    display:none !important;
}
```

**JS**

```jquery
$("#container").on('click', '.child', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('.parent').sortable({
    connectWith: '.parent, #container',
    appendTo: '#container',
    revert: 0,
    helper: 'clone',
    helper: function (e, item) {
        var helper = $('<div/>');
        if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
            item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
        var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
        item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
        return helper.append(elements);
    },
    start: function (e, ui) {
        var len = ui.helper.children().length;
        var width = ui.item.width() + 2;
        ui.helper.width((len * width));
        ui.placeholder.width((len * width));
    },
    stop: function (e, info) {
        info.item.after(info.item.data('multidrag')).remove();
    }
});

$('#container').sortable({
    connectWith: '.parent',
    tolerance: 'pointer'
});
```

If third-party `jQuery` plugins are allowed, take a look at https://github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. it seems to be working as it is but Unfortunately, this produces the same result when i add full width to the container as in my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6opxyvkp/8/ - drag an item out of the container and then hover it on the right side... placeholder is still in the `.parent`...

Comment: @TJ it's a known `sortable` glitch. It actually works but you need to move it well outside of the container after which slowly moving it to the left (when you want to add them to the right of the container) will give you an option to insert it outside the parent. Hope that makes sense if not I could screencast it for you on what I mean?

Comment: @TJ You Could add `<div class="left"></div>` right and mid and use a little bit of a padding so you can add the blocks easier. Just putting together a new fiddle for you.

Comment: @TJ Please find the new fiddle link above. Never mind the red background on each of them they are just there as a guide.

Comment: Sorry, adding new elements in `DOM` is not at all an option... this is just a demo, new parent groups will be generated by user interaction, so if there are 20 parents then i'll have to generate,    21 extra elements, keep track of them and remove it according to user interaction... that's why i was asked for a fix with sortable options and css if possible...

Comment: @TJ Sorry bro, not too sure what you're after... Looking back at your question above, the latest fiddle link I chucked up the top covers your 3 things you wanted to achieve. If there is anything else specific that you need please let us know.